# Need to return two values in a PHP if - else statement

Tags: php

I have the script below and I need to return both of the conditional `return` values -- each result on a line. Is there any way to format it as an array in order to work ?

The script is:

```
if ($pdf_url != '') {
    if ($title != '') {
        $title_from_url = $this->make_title_from_url($pdf_url);
        if ($title == $title_from_url || $this->make_title_from_url('/'.$title) == $title_from_url) {
            // This would be the default title anyway based on URL
            // OR if you take .pdf off title it would match, so that's close enough - don't load up shortcode with title param
            $title = '';
        } else {
            $title = ' title="' . esc_attr( $title ) . '"';
        }
    }
    return apply_filters('pdfemb_override_send_to_editor', '[pdf-embedder url="' . $pdf_url . '"'.$title.']', $html, $id, $attachment);
} else {
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: You can return them as an array or as an object. Instead of returning the values just store them in a variable (lets say `$var1` & `$var2`). (As an example of the array implementation `return ['var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2];`)

Comment: `return [ $foo, $bar ];` …?

Comment: Just as a note: there are multiple ways of handling this, but my first comment probably covers what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want each result on a line, it sounds like you could use a temporary variable, and concatenate to it based on the logic.

```
 <?php
      $output = '';
      if ($pdf_url != '') {
           if ($title != '') {
                $title_from_url = $this->make_title_from_url($pdf_url);
                if ($title == $title_from_url || $this->make_title_from_url('/'.$title) == $title_from_url) {
                     // This would be the default title anyway based on URL
                     // OR if you take .pdf off title it would match, so that's close enough - don't load up shortcode with title param
                     $title = '';
                } else {
                     $title = ' title="' . esc_attr( $title ) . '"';
                }
           }
           // You may need print_r() around apply_filters() if it returns an array
           $output .= apply_filters('pdfemb_override_send_to_editor', '[pdf-embedder url="' . $pdf_url . '"'.$title.']', $html, $id, $attachment) . "\n";
      } else {
           $output .= $html . "\n";
      }
      return $output;
```

Or if you want it in array:

```
 <?php
      $output = [];
      if ($pdf_url != '') {
           if ($title != '') {
                $title_from_url = $this->make_title_from_url($pdf_url);
                if ($title == $title_from_url || $this->make_title_from_url('/'.$title) == $title_from_url) {
                     // This would be the default title anyway based on URL
                     // OR if you take .pdf off title it would match, so that's close enough - don't load up shortcode with title param
                     $title = '';
                } else {
                     $title = ' title="' . esc_attr( $title ) . '"';
                }
           }
           // You may need print_r() around apply_filters() if it returns an array
           $output[] = apply_filters('pdfemb_override_send_to_editor', '[pdf-embedder url="' . $pdf_url . '"'.$title.']', $html, $id, $attachment);
      } else {
           $output[] = $html;
      }
      return $output;
```

Comment: hello,thanks for so quick answer. Both ways are giving me same error in website: There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.I will check logs to see if i can find more.

Comment: This is the error in debug.log: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) on that last else of the code (penultimate line of original code)

Comment: Can you see a line number referenced anywhere? I ran the code I sent you locally and I don't get that error.

Comment: @MariusS are you sure that you have properly opened/closed all curly braces?

Comment: full code here http://qqqq.ro/code.txt
whith this code now error is 
[15-Dec-2020 15:17:56 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED), expecting end of file in core_pdf_embedder.php on line 109

Comment: Thanks @MariusS, I've had a look, it seems when you pasted in the code from here, there was an extra curly brace added on line 108. So after `return $output;` there should only be 1x `}`.

Comment: Thanks @mikey . Now i don't have any error but as result i still have only the 1'st result (of this line return apply_filters('pdfemb_override_send_to_editor', '[pdf-embedder url="' . $pdf_url . '"'.$title.']', $html, $id, $attachment);) i also want to have the result of return $html; on the next line (now it is an else statement. I need both result). Thank you very much. All your help is appreciated.

Comment: No worries @MariusS, so the code you send us in that URL is using my 2nd example, perhaps try the first code block I sent instead. Without knowing where/how the output of that function is used it makes it hard to be certain.